# Creating a 3D buffer polygons (plane) from a 3D polyline that follow line catenary curvatures

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst

I am looking to create a 3D buffer polygon that represents a plane from a 3D polyline feature that represents an electric power (transmission) line. This polyline has Z-values that give it catenary curvatures when viewed in ArcScene. I am currently using ArcGIS and would prefer an ArcGIS method to add my current workflow. This plane is intended to differentiate vegetation points that are taller than the electric power line that could potentially fall in a strike the line wires.

Comment: Instead of creating a 3D plane to find vegetation points that are below or above the electric power I have begun testing the "Near 3D" functionality that will give the the angle value of nearest line to the vegetation points being examined.

Comment: "Near 3D" function ran for 16h 50m to find distance and angle for ≈300,000 points. Looking into an alternative using ArcScene to create a 3D feature exported by changing the power line symbol to "3D Simple Line Symbol" with style set to "Strip" + width value. This has created a 3D plane (multimatch).