# Creating planar 3D buffer from 3D polyline feature class in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, 3d-analyst, cut-fill

I want to create a planar (=without volume) buffer polygon or a TIN from a polyline feature class that represents a road centreline ,containing Z-value. I want to expand my polyline horizontally (=parallel to ground) in 3D environment to get a 3D polygon which its volume is zero. I tried to use buffer analysis tool and enabled z value, but it results in a polygon without elevation. What I want is as same as [Creating a 3D buffer polygons (plane) from a 3D polyline that follow line catenary curvatures](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225554) except my goal is to calculate the cut & fill for a road.

[image]

In the attached image, the black polyline represents road centreline. The black polygon is the result of buffering and the red polygon, is a polygon which represents terrain. My ultimate goal is to calculate the volume between two polygons or surfaces to get cut & fill.

How can I create my desired polygon or surface in ArcGIS Desktop?

I have a 3D Analyst license and am using ArcMap/ArcScene/etc.

Comment: Create tin using same points with z value set to zero.

Comment: @FelixIP which points?

Comment: Same points from which your time made up